# Von Neumann algebra generated by a subalgebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let A be a C*-algebra of operators on a Hilbert space H. Show that if $A\subset K(H)$, then $\{A'\cap K(H)\}'\cap K(H) = A$
I do not have any idea about it. Please give me a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated this result is false.

Take $H=\mathbb{C^n}$. Then, $K(H)=B(H)$. Let $A=\{0\}$.

Then, $A'=B(H)$. and we have:

$\{A' \cap K(H)\}' \cap K(H) = \mathbb{C}I \neq A$.

Note that $A$ is contained in LHS.

EDIT: I think the result is false in general as well. Here's the counterexample.

Let $e_1,e_2, \cdots$ be a basis of $H$. Let $A$ consist of operators $T$ such that $Te_1=ce_1$ and $Te_n=0, n \ge2$.

Then all $2$ by $2$ diagonal matrices belong to the LHS, but do not belong to $A$.

Comment: The same counterexample applies in an infinite dimensional case.  It's probably missing a nondegeneracy condition.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: No- the same counterexample doesn't apply in infinite dimensions, as the only scalar multiple of $I$ which is a compact operator is $0$. Note that $A$ is a subset of $K(H)$. I think one can show that the LHS is the norm closure of $A$, which is $A$ itself, by adapting the proof of the bi commutant theorem.

Comment: Oh yeah, wasn't thinking, thank you.

Comment: This is an exercise of Takesaki's operator theory.

Comment: @niki: Does he have the extra hypothesis that $H$ is infinite dimensional? Otherwise the result is false- as shown above.

Comment: No anything. But if we suppose $H$ is infinite dimentional, how does it prove?

Comment: @niki: If I knew the proof- I would supply it. My guess would be to try and use the double commutant theorem's proof- but I haven't thought of it very much.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I think the result is false in general. Please check my example, if you have time.

Comment: @niki: I think the result is false. Please check this example, which I have added as an edit.

Comment: I guess that Takesaki always assumes the nondegeneracy for a $C^*$-algebra, see question  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098630/show-that-a-nondegenerate-banach-algebra-is-a-c-algebra/1098638 Hence the question is probably ok. It is just a problem how to use von Neumann's double commutant theorem.